# Perform operation on multiple arraylists efficiently in Java

Tags: java, performance, arraylist

I have ArrayLists of doubles within an ArrayList. So it is something like this

```java
ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> x = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>();
```

I have 19 ArrayLists within my `x`. I have a method called `distance(ArrayList x, ArrayList y)` which computes the **distance** between ArrayLists `x` and `y` and returns a `double`. I want to compute the distance between every single vector and all others.

My method would be to do the following

```java
for(int i=0 ; i<(x.size()-1) ; i++)
    {
        for(int j=(i+1) ; j<x.size() ; j++)
        {
            System.out.println(distance( x.get(i) , x.get(j) ));
        }
    }
```

However, it does not look as efficient. The efficiency is O(N^2). **Efficiency** is VERY important to me. I need help to figure out what is the **MOST** efficient way of doing this operation.

Comment: You cannot avoid O(N^2), as you are generating N^2 output values.

Comment: In Java 8 you can use parallel stream processing.

Comment: @PM77-1: That won't help you (complexity-wise) unless your number of cores is a function of N.

Comment: While you cant avoid O(n^2) depending on what your doing with the list you could store that list of distances and update it using a method that would operate much faster. But this depends on your application

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I see... Thank you very much. There is no other way that's more efficient than what I wrote then...?

Comment: @ug_ Is it possible for you to elaborate please?

Comment: @Matin: From an algorithmic-complexity perspective, no.  From a pragmatic perspective, perhaps yes.  But it would depend heavily on the mathematical properties of `distance`, for a start.  (Specifically, does `dist(x,y)` and `dist(y,z)` tell you anything about `dist(x,z)`?)

Comment: Try caching the values instead of recomputing the distance everytime

Comment: @ParthSatra - Distance between each two points is calculated just once.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth - Theoretically - no. Since OP mentioned *19* lists, I assumed he was looking for a practical improvement.

Comment: @Matin well caching would only help if you used the result from the `distance` method many times in your application or if the `distance` method was very time or memory intensive. It really wouldnt improve the performance of the code given.

Answer (score -2):

If the performance hit is from the algorithm of `distance(x,y)` and you can't optimize it anyhow, why don't you start by trying to cache the result of distance for a given pair of (x,y)? If you do, please consider also the case where `distance(x,y) == distance(y,x)`.

Moreover, pre-calculate the `x.size()` and store it might save you some processing.

Comment: How would caching help?  Each pair is considered exactly once.

Comment: I don't quiet understand what you mean by caching

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth "Each pair is considered exactly once" was not mentioned in the original question.

Comment: @Matin If you are looking for optimizing the for loops, Oliver Charlesworth already answered.

However, as far as I know nowadays, `for` loops are not the main performance hit but what you do in each iteration is the main cause of performance degradation.

So the idea is not to reduce the number of iterations.

If the combination of all vectors might consist of duplicated pairs of (x,y) and the method `distance` is very complex, you might want to store the result of `distance(x,y)` in a dictionary for later use.

This would help you improve the performance.

Comment: @MarbleDaemon: It is. Look at the loop structure.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth `distance(x.get(i) , x.get(j))` only means that each `(i,j)` is considered once but the value of `x.get(i)` and `x.get(j)` might be duplicated. For example, consider this array `( (0.0, 1.0), (1.0, 0.0), (0.0, 1.0), ... )`. You would see that there will be 2 calculations that are repeated: `distance((0.0, 1.0), (1.0, 0.0))` and `distance((1.0, 0.0), (0.0, 1.0))`. If the method `distance(x,y)` is both complex and permutable, we can well store the first calculation's result and use it instead of recalling `distance`

Comment: You make a fair point ;)  However, I guess we'd need to know more about the typical values the OP's working with before being able t establish that caching would have an impact.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I agree